# Can't get exactly values from other page

Tags: php

I am trying to get score table from this page http://www.skysports.com/football/competitions/bundesliga/table. I do this with

```
$bundes = file('http://www.skysports.com/football/competitions/bundesliga/table');
```

And when i try to display array $bundes i do it with this:

```
echo '<pre>', print_r($bundes), '</pre>';
```

The code witch i try do display is displayed like this:

```
[1437] => 
[1022] => German Bundesliga 2015/16
#   Team    Pl  W   D   L   F   A   GD  Pts Last 6
1   [1059] => [1060] => Bayern Munich [1061] => [1062] =>   9   9   0   0   29  4   25  27  [1072] =>
[1073] =>
[1074] =>
```

This is the first row of table. And now i can display $bundes[1060] and i get output of Bayer Munich but how can i get values from $bundes[1062], values are 9, 9, 0, 0, 29, 4, 25 and 27? I need to display each of this values in `<td></td>`
When i try to echo $bundes[1062] i get nothing.

Comment: `file()` will read the input and store each newline-delimited piece of string into the array that is returned as a result. You cannot expect skysports to put newlines where it matters to you; you will have to do more intelligent parsing of the data if you are mining it without using proper data-formats like JSON.

Comment: Don't.  Its a breach of the terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more reliable way of extracting the data is using [DOM manipulation classes](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to do something like:

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.skysports.com/football/competitions/bundesliga/table');

$xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);
$rows = $xpath->query('//tbody/tr');

$data = [];

foreach ($rows as $i => $row) {
    $columns = $xpath->query('td', $row);

    foreach ($columns as $column) {
        $data[$i][] = trim($column->textContent);
    }
}

print_r($data);
```

Which gives you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Bayern Munich
            [2] => 9
            [3] => 9
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 29
            [7] => 4
            [8] => 25
            [9] => 27
            [10] => 
        )
...
```

Regarding Dagon's comment, no terms can disallow crawling and extracting the data (as long as you do so at a reasonable rate that does not impact the website's performance). **Terms of use & copyright law, however, do dictate what you *can and cannot do with the crawled content (ex. republish).***

> Web scraping may be against the terms of use of some websites. The enforceability of these terms is unclear *(see ["FAQ about linking – Are website terms of use binding contracts?"](http://www.chillingeffects.org/linking/faq.cgi#QID596))*.
>
> *- Wikipedia, [Web scraping: Legal issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping#Legal_issues)*

BTW, the pages [robots meta tag](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html) does allow INDEX.

Comment: Yeah, but index is something else then rip. I couldn't care less if you would proceed, but bear in mind that it is actually against their terms (maybe even law?) to strip content of their site without consent and their knowledge. They would probably not notice it if you don't scrape content too often and if your site will not be that big. But know what you are doing!

Comment: 2.7 You will not copy, download, reproduce, republish, frame, broadcast, transmit in any manner whatsoever, any material on the Sky Site except as is strictly necessary for Your own personal non-commercial home use. http://help.sky.com/articles/skycom-terms-and-conditions

2.8 You will not access the Sky Site by automated means or otherwise for the purposes of scraping, extracting, or otherwise obtaining any material from the Sky Site (including TV listings) for use within a third party Website or application.